# Changing PNR flight segment status to KK or KL for testing purpose

Tags: sabre

I would like to have PNR (possibly in testing environment) with flight segment statuses KK or KL in PNR for Saber system.

I want to test retrieving from queue based on segment statuses (`QueueAccessLLSRQ` command with `<Selection Criteria="K" Function="AC"/>` filter) and changing them to `HK` (with `SabreCommandLLSRQ` command `.1/2HK`).

Answer (score 1):

These are the action codes you can use when adding passive segments:

Confirmed:
GK
BK
HK
YK
DS

Waitlisted:
GL
BL
HL

Source: https://formatfinder.sabre.com/Content/AirTravel/SellAirSegment/PassiveSegmentsOverviewandFormats.aspx?ItemID=b058464e891c46378d7a717d7810b4ec